# ServerAliveInterval and connection reset

Tags: linux, ssh, networking, sftp

If I run:

```
sftp -oServerAliveInterval=10 server-2
```

Connection is established. But after increasing (decreasing) the value from 10 to 1:

```
sftp -oServerAliveInterval=1 server-2
```

I am unable to connect:

```
Connecting to server-2...
Connection closed by 10.0.1.10
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

Any ideas why?

Added -vvv:

```
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: id_rsa (0xxxxxxxxxxx)
Connection to 10.0.1.10 timed out while waiting to read
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: check with verbose log (`-vvv` switches). It will give you the clue.

Comment: Nothing interesting: 

debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: id_rsa (0xxxxxxxxxxx)
Connection to 10.0.1.10 timed out while waiting to read
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Issue caused by internal bug in the app server running on Windows machine

Answer (score 0):

> But after increasing (decreasing) the value from 10 to 1:

```
sftp -oServerAliveInterval=1 server-2
```

Setting `ServerAliveInterval` to `1` second starts timer after every read and if there are no other data, it queries the server for response. If defined amount of answers will not return (`ServerAliveCountMax` is also important in this context), then the connection is closed.

This is also related to `TCPKeepAlive`, which does basically the same without too much burden. The above mentioned options should be used only if the `TCPKeepAlive` is not effective and you see a lot of connection breakage.

Mentioning in your question *why* you did this would also help.

Comment: I know what this setting does, but I still do not know why it keeps disconnecting BEFORE the connection has been established. Why I did this? If there is such setting I would like to understand how it works

Comment: and also because I do see a lot of connecion breakage

Comment: To know why, you would have to post the whole `-vvv` output. I might have a look into that. It is possible that in this early stage the remote side is unable to answer you every second, so your client breaks the connection (as log proposes).

Comment: -vvv didnt provide much details. even strace did not provide anything interesting. During the connection I do not see additional packets being sent (iwth setting set to 1 or 10).